# Failed to install a package. Error: System command error, exit status: -1, stdout + stderr empty,

Tags: r

I've tried to install a package for almost 2 days but installation has not been working by now. I tried a lot of different ways like

```
install.packages("NIADic_0.0.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

then 
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘NIADic_0.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

and

```
devtools::install_local('C://Users/pogr1/Desktop/NIADic_0.0.1.tar.gz', force = TRUE)
```

then
Error: Failed to install 'NIADic' from local:
  System command error, exit status: -1, stdout + stderr empty

```
install.packages("https://github.com/haven-jeon/NIADic/releases/download/0.0.1/NIADic_0.0.1.tar.gz",
                 lib = .libPaths()[1], repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

then
cannot open compressed file 'NIADic_0.0.1.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

and even I reinstalled R, rstudio, and Rtools but still not working

```
- Session info     
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Korean_Korea.949            
 ctype    Korean_Korea.949            
 tz       Asia/Seoul                  
 date     2019-10-31
```

plz help :(

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a bit old... The package needs [`RTools`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html) for compilation, but then it needs `pandoc`, package `data.table` etc. to build vignettes. If you want to proceed easily only with package itself without docs, it should work to have RTools installed and then run:

```
devtools::install_github('haven-jeon/NIADic/NIADic', build_vignettes = FALSE)
```